# Can I use the EV3 IR Sensor with a power functions remote?

Tags: ev3, power-functions, sensor

In other words, I want to control my Lego Mindstorms EV3 robot with my Lego
Power Functions remotes. The EV3 has an IR sensor, and the PF remotes are IR Remotes, but will they work together?

Answer (score 3):

The EV3 IR Sensor is compatible with [Power Functions 8885 remote](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/lego-power-functions-ir-remote-control-8885) the but not the [8879 remote](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/6092/3498).